# Byte data type an throws error when compiled

Tags: c#

it throws the error `` main.cs(27,9): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `byte', expecting `class', `delegate', `enum', `interface', `partial', `ref', or `struct' ``
github repo [here](https://github.com/staticvoidliam7/Argon/tree/Development-(Unstable))
this code is from [here](https://medium.com/@kusumatomy/developing-simple-crypto-application-using-c-48258c2d4e45). I am using Mono 6.12.0.90. I am using the Byte data type.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

public class Transaction
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Sender { set; get; }
   public string Recipient { set; get; }
   public decimal Amount { set; get; }
   public decimal Fee { set; get; }
}

public class Block
{
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public Int64 TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public byte[] PrevHash { get; set; }
    public byte[] Hash { get; set; }
    public Transaction[] Transactions { get; set; }
    public string Creator { get; set; }
}
  

  public byte[] GenerateHash()
{
    var sha = SHA256.Create();
    
    //convert current timestamp to array of byte
    byte[] timeStamp = BitConverter.GetBytes(TimeStamp);

    //convert transaction collection to array of byte
    var transactionHash = Transactions.ConvertToByte();

    //make block header in array of byte
    byte[] headerBytes = new byte[timeStamp.Length + PrevHash.Length + transactionHash.Length];

    Buffer.BlockCopy(timeStamp, 0, headerBytes, 0, timeStamp.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(PrevHash, 0, headerBytes, timeStamp.Length, PrevHash.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(transactionHash, 0, headerBytes, timeStamp.Length + PrevHash.Length, transactionHash.Length);

    byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(headerBytes);

    return hash;

}

class main{
  static void Main(){
  

  }
}
```

I am using Repl.it as my development environment, and am running the program via a bash project using Mono.

i just want it to run without errors at this point lol

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtsdO.png)

Comment: Please, always post all relevant code **inside the question**.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! As other's have mentioned, it's always a great idea to provide all relevant code so we can help, since then, you've updated your post to include these details. The issue is `GenerateHash()`, it isn't inside a class, struct etc. Move that routine inside of `Main` and your problems are fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed above by @Codexer, you need to wrap up all `methods` inside a `class` in `C#`, otherwise, you are going to get `compilation errors`.
[C# Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods)
Hope this helps!

Comment: oh wait duh i should have remembered that lol thanks both of you